# Simultaneous Execution of Functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, execution

I am creating an application which must execute a function that takes too long (lets call it `slowfunc()`), which is a problem, since my application is working with a  live video feed. By running this function every frame, the frame rate is severely affected.

Is there a way to run `slowfunc()` in the background without using threading? I don't necessarily need it to run every frame, but every time it finishes, I'd like to examine the output. The only thing I can think of right now is to split up `slowfunc()` into several "mini-functions" which would each take approximately an equal amount of time, then run one minifunction per frame. However, `slowfunc()` is a relatively complex function, and I feel that there should be (hopefully is) a way to do this simply.

EDIT: I can't use threading because this program will eventually be used on a tiny robot processor which probably will not support threading. I guess I can use "cooperative multitasking". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Threads are a simple and natural way to do this. Please explain why you can't use threading. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the simple way to do it is with threading. If you won't do that, your only other option is to break it up into pieces.

Comment: How could you run something in the background without threading?  I mean...that's like finding a way to breathe without air.  You could write another program and start it from your program I suppose...but that's still threading, its just being done by the OS for you.

Comment: @Chad, you just run a piece of the process and let it return back to you when it's done; it even has a name when used at the OS level, cooperative multitasking. It can be less error prone and easier to debug than full threading if done properly.

Comment: @Mark I understand what you're saying, but that's not really running anything in the background.  Its explicitly running things in your single line of execution, just in pieces.  I guess its kinda sorta like being your own scheduler except not really.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that you can use the phrases 'live video feed' and 'tiny robot processor which probably will not support threading' in the same post.  If it can support video, it can support an  embedded multitasker, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it in a thread and after the calculation is finished, make the thread sleep until another calculation is ready to be run. That way you are not hit with the initialization of the thread every time.

Comment: Of the two answers, this was the closest to what I had wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for simaltaneous execution.  The two ways to do this are -:
a) Multi-threading -: Create another thread to run on a background.
b) MUlti-processing -: Create another process . Take all inputs required for the function via a shared memory model. Create a synchronisation mechanism with original process(parent process). Execute this function.

It is normally prefered to use the 1st one. Faster execution.

The 2nd one guarantees that if the function crashes your parent process still runs. Although, that is a bit irrelevant since, why would you want your child(function) to crash. This needs more memory.